# Office Web Apps certificate issue

Tags: office-web-apps, certificate

I followed this [instruction](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office_web_apps_server_2013_support_blog/2013/12/20/office-web-apps-2013-rebuild-your-farm-in-a-few-easy-steps/) to rebuild our OWA farm, and as we only have 1 OWA server the only thing I did was step 5 of this instruction.
Everything works fine now from internal network, but when users are trying to open a document from the external network they get this:
"content was blocked because it was not signed by a valid security certificate"
[image]

Is there anything I'm missing that had to be done?

```
Get-officewebappsfarm output: 
FarmOU : 
InternalURL : officewebapps.contoso.com 
ExternalURL : officewebapps.contoso.com 
AllowHTTP : True 
SSLOffloaded : False 
CertificateName : OWA 
EditingEnabled : True 
LogLocation : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS 
LogRetentionInDays : 7 
LogVerbosity : 
Proxy :
CacheLocation : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Working\d 
MaxMemoryCacheSizeInMB : 75 
DocumentInfoCacheSize : 5000 
CacheSizeInGB : 15 
ClipartEnabled : False 
TranslationEnabled : False 
MaxTranslationCharacterCount : 125000 
TranslationServiceAppId : 
TranslationServiceAddress : 
RenderingLocalCacheLocation : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Working\waccache 
RecycleActiveProcessCount : 5 
AllowCEIP : False
ExcelRequestDurationMax : 300
ExcelSessionTimeout : 450 
ExcelWorkbookSizeMax : 10 
ExcelPrivateBytesMax : -1 
ExcelConnectionLifetime : 1800 
ExcelExternalDataCacheLifetime : 300 
ExcelAllowExternalData : True 
ExcelWarnOnDataRefresh : True 
OpenFromUrlEnabled : False 
OpenFromUncEnabled : True 
OpenFromUrlThrottlingEnabled : True 
PicturePasteDisabled : True 
RemovePersonalInformationFromLogs : False 
AllowHttpSecureStoreConnections : False
IgnoreDeserializationFilter : False Machines : {OFFICEWA}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the office web apps url was https, make sure you have a correct certificate (that's not expired) to it. Use:

```
Set-OfficeWebAppsFarm -CertificateName "Certificate Friendly Name"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47153/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-office-web-apps-certificate-issue).